# Undefined when trying to access an array inside nested queries

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I know this problem has something to do with callbacks, but I just can't solve it. After hours of research I decided to post it.
This is my code:

```
function getTables(callback)
{ 
connection.query('show tables', function (error, allQueries, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        else{
            for(var i=0;i<allQueries.length;i++){
                tables.push(allQueries[i].Tables_in_ProyectoFinal);
            }
            callback(tables);
        }
});
}

getTables(function (tables){
    for(var i = 0;i < tables.length; i++){
        connection.query('show columns from ' + tables[i], function (error, allColumns, fields) {
                if (error) throw error;
                else{
                    for(var j = 0;j < allColumns.length; j++){
                        //columns.push("select " + allColumns[j].Field + " from "+ tables[i]);
                        console.log("Column: "+allColumns[j].Field+" from table: "+ tables[i]);
                    }
                }
        });
    }


});
```

I get this results:

```
Column: peliculaId from table: undefined
Column: titulo from table: undefined
Column: ano from table: undefined
Column: personaId from table: undefined
Column: nombre from table: undefined
Column: apellido from table: undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `allQueries[i].Tables_in_ProyectoFinal` is coming up as `undefined`. Check that the property is spelled correctly and that it exists on each object in the allQueries array.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are facing this issue is because the value of `i` is already 1 more than the length of the tables array.

`connection.query` is async. This means that for loop with tables is gonna run and not wait for the callback to finish. 
I am sure if you put `console.log(i)` in the `for loop` with `j`, you will get `i = tables.length`

Looks at this example below

```js
function myAsyncFunction(tableName, callbackFunction) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('table name', tableName);
    callbackFunction(null, ['column1', 'column2']);

  }, 100);
}

function getTables(tables) {
  for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
    myAsyncFunction(tables[i], function (error, allColumns) {
      for (var j = 0; j < allColumns.length; j++) {
        console.log('i is', i);
        console.log('tables', tables[i]);
      }
    })
  }
};

getTables(['table1', 'table2']);
```

The value of `i` is 2

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers. I solved it this way:

```
function getTables(callback)
{ 
connection.query('show tables', function (error, allQueries, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        else{
            for(var i=0;i<allQueries.length;i++){
                tables.push(allQueries[i].Tables_in_ProyectoFinal);
                columns.push("SELECT *  FROM " +allQueries[i].Tables_in_ProyectoFinal);
            }
            callback(tables);
        }
});
}
function getAll(table,callback)
{ 
connection.query('show columns from ' + table, function (error, allColumns, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        else{
            for(var j = 0;j < allColumns.length; j++){
                //console.log("Column: "+allColumns[j].Field+" from table: "+ table);
                columns.push("SELECT "+allColumns[j].Field+" FROM "+ table)
            }
            callback(columns);
        }

});
}

getTables(function (tables){
    for(var i = 0;i < tables.length; i++){
        getAll(tables[i],function(columns){
            console.log(columns);
        });
    }
});
```

I built the two functions with callbacks